# Live Leaderboard Website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, leaderboard

i'm here with a big question :p
In first sorry for my english, i'm french

So, i have website, i practice crossfit ( You know ? the sport ) and i want to make a live leaderboard on my website, it make in wordpress.

So my question is : Do you have some ideas to help me ? I'm looking for create this leaderboard in ruby on rails but.. i'm not sure. So you thinks that is it possible to create with other technologies or with wordpress ? or ruby if it's possible (Currently i use google sheet and plugin wpdatatable) but i want to synchronize sending a team's score via a form and then process the data on google sheet or other and display them.

Thanks for all ideas , and ask me if you want ! Regards :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, this site is not the best place to ask a general question like this- this question is going to get downvoted and/or closed. Once you get started with your code, people here will help you with very specific problems you encounter - have a look at some highly upvoted questions to see what this site is about.